# VS code unresolved import

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a weird problem with vs code using python. I set the interpreter to be a virtual environment outside of my project and everything works well, but when I install a dependency, vs code doesn't stop highlighting that the package is missing. I can run the code OK, just that the editor doesn't realize the package is installed. Actually, when I reboot vs code, the highlighting goes away. Is there some kind of setting I'm missing?

Comment: if the environment set in vscode is same as that of external virtual environment then it should work .

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why. I have the .vscode folder with the setting to the venv set as well. It's just the highlighting, everything else works.